# How can I speed up git reset --hard HEAD

Tags: git

Our CI loop speeds up pulling from git by avoiding updating the index when it downloads.  At the end of the build, it runs git reset --hard HEAD and git clean -fdx out of precaution in case any build steps accidentally changed source files.  The problem is that git reset --hard HEAD takes a long time, like 4-20 minutes.  Part of this is due to the fact that it has to rebuild the index.  I have solved the index rebuild issue by calling 'git reset' in parallel with the build.  This should be safe as it doesn't actually modify the file system.  I assume most of the rest of the time is coming from scanning the files in our large repo to get their timestamps and such.  I am wondering if there is a good way to update this information with another command run in parallel with the build that is non-intrusive (won't change source files).  I have been looking at git update-index, but I'm not sure what arguments are appropriate in this case.  Is git update-index the right command, and if so, how should I call it?

Comment: Does your CI need write access to the repo itself?

Comment: More than 4min for a reset is not normal. You should have something very specific or that you are doing wrong in your repo. Is creating a new 'worktree' each time and deleting it after the build is quicker? Maybe setting 'assume-unchanged' flage on some specific big files that doesn't change could help... Difficult to say without investigation.....

Comment: @Jim Redmond, no it doesn't, but it is hard to be 100% sure no one is touching any files there, and if they do, we don't want future builds to take their changes.

Comment: @Tony We are using a custom tool to download files instead of git because it is faster.  Git pull is too slow for our large repos.  It doesn't bother updating the index to save time as well.  Still takes a minute or two just to get new changes, which is unforunate...

Comment: @philippe we don't have a normal sized repo :)  Probably in the millions of files, and the outputs are about 6TB in size.  I believe when I logged onto the CI builder and ran the command myself several times, it never took quicker than 2 minutes.

Comment: Something I never encounter so I will be of little help. Did you have a look at "Git Scalar" made to manage huge repositories like yours: https://git-scm.com/docs/scalar

Comment: It's seems part of Scalar but it's also a good practice : put build artifacts in a specific subdirectory so that you can delete it before your git reset. Maybe it could speed up the process...